# why sending emails do not work in android studio's emulator?

Tags: android, email

I have created a situation where the user can send mail. I ran it on my mobile and it works, however it is not working in my emulator. It says some apps cannot perform this action. Help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: install play store.apk, then install gmail.apk You can find some apk-s from google

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation: [Android Email Intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email)

> If you are using an emulator, you’ll need to configure the email client. If the email client is not configured, it will not respond to the Intent we’ll be discussing. If you want to see the chooser in action, you’ll need to configure a device using multiple messaging applications, such as the Gmail application and the Email application.

In other words the emulator do not have an email app so you need to install one.
Hope it helps.